# Squeaking Cabinet Hinges

Tags: cabinets, hinges

My kitchen has old Grass brand 850-01 wrap around hinges that are starting to squeak.

Based on advice from online sources, including one older question here, I tried using silicone lubricant spray.  If anything, it made the problem worse and now the squeak has become a squawk with loud snapping sounds.

I took some measurements and found the newer part number with the added soft close feature from the manufacturer's website and ordered a set of hinges from a retailer.

Is there anything else to try in the meantime?  If I get good results with replacement hinges should I assume the old ones are just worn out?

Answer (score -1):

I removed the old hinges and tried spraying the springs and rollers from the back side.  That made the problem even worse.

The new soft-close hinges were not an exact match.  These extra tasks were needed to install them:

1. Remove the 4 plastic dowels from the door.
2. Expect some surface damage around the dowel holes especially with MDF doors.
3. Drill 4 pilot holes in the door for the new screws.
4. Mount and adjust the door using the new screws.  The old truss head screws won't fit in the frame slot.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question. Installing new hinges is not related to fixing a squeak in the old hinges.

Comment: @Isherwood  The squeak is gone now and the door works better than ever.  I'd say the fix is quite satisfactory.